# Is there any way to get and set settings of about:flags page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension and need to implement an API to change settings in Chrome.

I find all the settings in about:flags page, but I cannot find extension API to get or set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

The options in `chrome://flags` are intended for Chrome developers, not for end users. Flags are typically *not* permanent, as they are used for features that are still under development and testing, or features which are only used for testing. Once testing is complete, the flag is removed.

In short: flags are not a stable interface. Extensions should not depend on features controlled by flags. If a feature your extension needs is only available through a flag, it is not ready for general use yet, and you should wait until that changes.

Comment: Thx. BTW is there any settings page in Chrome like about:config in Firefox?

Comment: None that I'm aware of, unfortunately.